# How can I change doubled-up quote characters to only one character with sed?

Tags: unix, sed

I have a `tmp.cmd` file I am stripping of specific quotation marks.
It looks like this:

```
"grep -rFIil ""ACTVY_LOG""| xargs grep -iF ""ACTVY_ENT"""
"grep -rFIil ""ACTVY_LOG""| xargs grep -iF ""ACTVY_PTR"""
```

I want it to look like this:

```
grep -rFIil "ACTVY_LOG"| xargs grep -iF "ACTVY_ENT"
grep -rFIil "ACTVY_LOG"| xargs grep -iF "ACTVY_PTR"
```

I have been able to strip the first and last quotation using this command:
`sed -r 's/^"|"$//g' tmp.cmd > tmp1.cmd`.
So that it looks like this `grep -rFIil ""APE.ACTVY_LOG""| xargs grep -iF ""ACTVY_ENT_TSTMP""`.

How can I remove the other quotations? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change `""` to `"`, that's `s/""/"/g`.

Thus:

```
sed -e 's/^"//' -e 's/"$//' -e 's/""/"/g'
```

See this running against your stated input in an online sandbox at https://ideone.com/WOuXjU